# In R, how can loop multiple variable at the same?

Tags: r, loops

I am wondering of how can I loop the multiple variables at the same time in R.

For example,

```
a = c(1, 2, 3)
b = c(4, 5, 6)
```

And then for loop, the below code didnt work.

```
for (i, j in a, b) {
    print(i)
    print(j)
}
```

In Python,

```
for i,j in zip(a,b):
  print(i)
  print(j)
```

it is possible. How can I do this in R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip or enumerate in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281323/zip-or-enumerate-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using R, in this case the best solution is to iterate over the length of one array and print the value in the position of each array:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3)
b = c(4, 5, 6)
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
  print(a[i])
  print(b[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, it's even simpler:

```
mapply(function(x,y) print(x,y), a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all 9 possible combinations, you need to use a nested for loop

```
a = c(1, 2, 3)
b = c(4, 5, 6)
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
  for(j in 1:length(b))
  {
    print(a[i])
    print(b[j])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `seq_along`

```
for(i in seq_along(a)) {
   print(a[i])
   print(b[i])
  }
```