# Extract object from list using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

This is related to the questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27100678/209882) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530217/in-r-extract-part-of-object-from-list)

I have a list of objects (in my case they are also lists AFAII), as returned by running:

```
gof_stats <- models %>% map(gof_stats)
```

Where `models` is a list of models created by `fitdistrplus` and `gof_stats` is a function that computes goodness of fit stats for each model.

Now if I want to extract a specific stat from that list I could do something like:

```
gof_stats[[1]]$cvm
```

to get the Cramer von Mises stat. I can achieve the same over the whole list (as per the linked questions) like so:

```
cvms <- sapply(gof_stats, "[[", "cvm")
```

Is there a way to do the same using `dplyr`/`purrr` syntax?

BONUS: How would you handle the case where some of the elements in the `models` list are `NULL`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you prefer `map` to `sapply` for this, you can do

```
library(purrr)
map(gof_stats, ~ .x[["cvm"]])
```

If you just like pipes you could do

```
gof_stats %>% sapply("[[", "cvm")
```

Your question is about lists, not data frames, so `dplyr` doesn't really apply. You may want to look up `?magrittr::multiply_by` to see a list of other aliases from the package that defines `%>%` as you seem to like piping. For example, `magrittr::extract2` is an alias of `[[` that can be easily used in the middle of a piping chain.

As for your bonus, I would pre-filter the list to remove `NULL` elements before attempting to extract things.

Comment: Could you explain what the tilde `~` does in the map solution?

Comment: See `?map`, under *Arguments*, `.f`, *If a formula, e.g. `~ .x + 2`...*. It's also used in the examples. If you want more detail, have a look at the [vignette of the `lazyeval` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html). Essentially the `~` is used to coerce the expression that follows to be a formula.

Comment: Or just "cvm" because string inputs are used as indexes

Answer (score 0):

A solution composed completely of tidyverse functions is:

```
gof_stats %>%
   map(~ .x %>% pluck("cvm"))
```

Legend:

- `map` is the tidyverse function for lists, replacing the `apply` family
- `.x` is the object in each iteration
- `~` is the purrr short syntax for the anonymous function `function(x) { }`
- `pluck` extracts a list element by index or string