# Calculate vector whose length is not known beforehand - should I "grow" it?

Tags: r, performance, vector, allocation

I need to calculate entries of a vector *whose length I do not know beforehand*. How to do so efficiently?

A trivial solution is to "grow" it: start with a small or empty vector and successively append new entries until the stopping criterion is reached. For example:

```
foo <- numeric(0)
while ( sum(foo) < 100 ) foo <- c(foo,runif(1))
length(foo)
# 195
```

However, "growing" vectors is frowned upon in R for performance reasons.

Of course, I could "grow it in chunks": pre-allocate a "good-sized" vector, fill it, double its length when it is full, and finally cut it down to size. But this feels error-prone and will make for inelegant code.

Is there a better or canonical way to do this? (In my actual application, the calculation and the stopping criterion are a bit more complicated, of course.)

---

**In reply to some useful comments**

> Even if you don't know the length beforehand, do you know the maximum possible length it can theoretically have? In such cases I tend to initialize the vector with that length and after the loop cut the NAs or remove the unused entries based on the latest index value.

No, the maximum length is not known in advance.

> Do you need to keep all values as the vector grows?

Yes, I do.

> What about something like `rand_num <- runif(300); rand_num[cumsum(rand_num) < 100]` where you choose a sufficiently large vector that you know for a high probability that the condition will be met? You can of course check it and use an even bigger number if it's not met. I've tested up till `runif(10000)` it's still faster than "growing".

My actual use case involves a dynamic calculation, which I can't simply vectorize (otherwise I would not be asking).

Specifically, to approximate the convolution of negative binomial random variables, I need to calculate the probability masses of the integer random variable $K$ in Theorem 2 in [Furman, 2007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2006.06.007) up to a high cumulative probability. These masses $pr_k$ involve some intricate recursive sums.

Comment: How about create a list and add each current vector as an element of the list and at the end unlist the list?

Comment: @user2974951: I thought about that. But to be honest, if growing a *numeric vector* is problematic in terms of performance, I would expect growing a *list* that only included single numerics and finally `unlist`ing it to be even worse... I may profile it a bit.

Comment: You can expand in chunks rather than for each element.

Comment: This is a great question but I wonder whether in your case whether just growing the vector is really going to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Hugh depending on the size of the vectors it might be, since as I understand it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603318/9811316, R simply copies the vector components into the new object, meaning the larger the object the higher the cost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could "grow it in chunks": pre-allocate a "good-sized" vector, fill it, double its length when it is full, and finally cut it down to size. But this feels error-prone and will make for inelegant code.

Sounds like you are referring to the accepted answer of [Collecting an unknown number of results in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16512371/4891738). Have you coded it up and tried it? The idea of length doubling is more than sufficient (see the end of this answer), as the length will grow geometrically. I will demonstrate my method in the following.

---

For test purpose, wrap your code in a function. Note how I avoid doing `sum(z)` for every `while` test.

```
ref <- function (stop_sum, timing = TRUE) {
  set.seed(0)                            ## fix a seed to compare performance
  if (timing) t1 <- proc.time()[[3]]
  z <- numeric(0)
  sum_z <- 0
  while ( sum_z < stop_sum ) {
    z_i <- runif(1)
    z <- c(z, z_i)
    sum_z <- sum_z + z_i
    }
  if (timing) {
    t2 <- proc.time()[[3]]
    return(t2 - t1)                      ## return execution time
    } else {
    return(z)                            ## return result
    }
  }
```

Chunking is necessary to reduce the operational costs of concatenation.

```
template <- function (chunk_size, stop_sum, timing = TRUE) {
  set.seed(0)                            ## fix a seed to compare performance
  if (timing) t1 <- proc.time()[[3]]
  z <- vector("list")                    ## store all segments in a list
  sum_z <- 0                             ## cumulative sum
  while ( sum_z < stop_sum ) {
    segmt <- numeric(chunk_size)         ## initialize a segment
    i <- 1
    while (i <= chunk_size) {
      z_i <- runif(1)                    ## call a function & get a value
      sum_z <- sum_z + z_i               ## update cumulative sum
      segmt[i] <- z_i                    ## fill in the segment
      if (sum_z >= stop_sum) break       ## ready to break at any time
      i <- i + 1
      }
    ## grow the list
    if (sum_z < stop_sum) z <- c(z, list(segmt))
    else z <- c(z, list(segmt[1:i]))
    }
  if (timing) {
    t2 <- proc.time()[[3]]
    return(t2 - t1)                      ## return execution time
    } else {
    return(unlist(z))                    ## return result
    }
  }
```

Let's check correctness first.

```
z <- ref(1e+4, FALSE)
z1 <- template(5, 1e+4, FALSE)
z2 <- template(1000, 1e+4, FALSE)

range(z - z1)
#[1] 0 0

range(z - z2)
#[1] 0 0
```

Let's then compare speed.

```
## reference implementation
t0 <- ref(1e+4, TRUE)

## unrolling implementation
trial_chunk_size <- seq(5, 1000, by = 5)
tm <- sapply(trial_chunk_size, template, stop_sum = 1e+4, timing = TRUE)

## visualize timing statistics
plot(trial_chunk_size, tm, type = "l", ylim = c(0, t0), col = 2, bty = "l")
abline(h = t0, lwd = 2)
```

Looks like `chunk_size = 200` is sufficiently good, and the speedup factor is

```
t0 / tm[trial_chunk_size == 200]
#[1] 16.90598
```

[image]

Let's finally see how much time is spent for growing vector with `c`, via profiling.

```
Rprof("a.out")
z0 <- ref(1e+4, FALSE)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("a.out")$by.self
#        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"c"          1.68    90.32       1.68     90.32
#"runif"      0.12     6.45       0.12      6.45
#"ref"        0.06     3.23       1.86    100.00

Rprof("b.out")
z1 <- template(200, 1e+4, FALSE)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("b.out")$by.self
#        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"runif"      0.10    83.33       0.10     83.33
#"c"          0.02    16.67       0.02     16.67
```

---

#### Adaptive `chunk_size` with linear growth

`ref` has `O(N * N)` operational complexity where `N` is the length of the final vector. `template` in principle has `O(M * M)` complexity, where `M = N / chunk_size`. To attain linear complexity `O(N)`, `chunk_size` needs to grow with `N`, but a linear growth is sufficient: `chunk_size <- chunk_size + 1`.

```
template1 <- function (chunk_size, stop_sum, timing = TRUE) {
  set.seed(0)                            ## fix a seed to compare performance
  if (timing) t1 <- proc.time()[[3]]
  z <- vector("list")                    ## store all segments in a list
  sum_z <- 0                             ## cumulative sum
  while ( sum_z < stop_sum ) {
    segmt <- numeric(chunk_size)         ## initialize a segment
    i <- 1
    while (i <= chunk_size) {
      z_i <- runif(1)                    ## call a function & get a value
      sum_z <- sum_z + z_i               ## update cumulative sum
      segmt[i] <- z_i                    ## fill in the segment
      if (sum_z >= stop_sum) break       ## ready to break at any time
      i <- i + 1
      }
    ## grow the list
    if (sum_z < stop_sum) z <- c(z, list(segmt))
    else z <- c(z, list(segmt[1:i]))
    ## increase chunk_size
    chunk_size <- chunk_size + 1
    }
  ## remove this line if you want
  cat(sprintf("final chunk size = %d\n", chunk_size))
  if (timing) {
    t2 <- proc.time()[[3]]
    return(t2 - t1)                      ## return execution time
    } else {
    return(unlist(z))                    ## return result
    }
  }
```

A quick test verifies that we have attained linear complexity.

```
template1(200, 1e+4)
#final chunk size = 283
#[1] 0.103

template1(200, 1e+5)
#final chunk size = 664
#[1] 1.076

template1(200, 1e+6)
#final chunk size = 2012
#[1] 10.848

template1(200, 1e+7)
#final chunk size = 6330
#[1] 108.183
```