# In which cases would operations on a pairlist will outperform a list?

Tags: r, list, linked-list

From previous questions I've learned that `pairlist` is a type of linked-list in R (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417134/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-a-pairlist-in-r)).

So it is true in the sense that getting the length of a `pairlist` takes MUCH longer than getting the length of a `list`. Hypothetically, it should take longer to insert or remove an element in a list than in pairlist (since pairlist is a linked list, is it not?). But this is also slower.

For example:

```
list1 <- as.list(1:1e4)
pairlist1 <- as.pairlist(list1)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(length(list1), length(pairlist1)) # this is indeed a linked list! (it is much slower)
microbenchmark(list1[-1], pairlist1[-1]) # why is list faster?
```

And the output is:

```
> microbenchmark(length(list1), length(pairlist1)) # this is indeed a linked list! (it is much slower)
Unit: nanoseconds
              expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval cld
     length(list1)     0     0    46.85      0     1   3105   100  a 
 length(pairlist1) 62388 62389 70808.86  62698 68130 190888   100   b
Warning message:
In microbenchmark(length(list1), length(pairlist1)) :
  Could not measure a positive execution time for 21 evaluations.
> microbenchmark(list1[-1], pairlist1[-1]) # why is list faster?
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     list1[-1]  76.045  84.1155 111.0971  88.1500  96.9965 1882.807   100  a 
 pairlist1[-1] 238.998 257.7765 356.8178 266.6225 299.6790 3281.719   100   b
```

The same is true about the size of the object. For example:

```
library(pryr)
sizes <- sapply(0:50, function(n) object_size(as.pairlist(seq_len(n))))
plot(0:50, sizes, xlab = "Length", ylab = "Size (bytes)",   type = "s")
#sizes2 <- sapply(0:50, function(n) object_size((seq_len(n))))
sizes2 <- sapply(0:50, function(n) object_size(as.list(seq_len(n))))
lines(0:50, sizes2, xlab = "Length", ylab = "Size (bytes)",   type = "s", col = 2)
legend("topleft", fill = c(1,2), legend = c("pairlist", "list") )
```

[image]

So my questions are:
1. why is it slower to insert/remove an element? (/ is there a way to make it faster in pairlist than in a list?)
2. Are there cases in which an operation on a pairlist will outperform a list?

Comment: IMO because in R objects are not mutable, so probably removing 1 element causes the copy of a whole new list in both cases... and of course a linked list takes longer to be copied than a vector

Comment: Thanks @digEmAll, that makes sense. So is there a situation in which pairlist would in anyway out-perform a list? (I've updated my question)

Comment: Mmh... I doubt a pairlist can outperform a list when used in R... another story if when you use it in C/C++, there you can modify the object in place, exploiting the linked-list features...

Comment: Can you think of a simple Rcpp example for that?

Comment: Wait a minute : [according to this doc](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects), pairlists are converted to lists when used/subsetted in R, so I think that's the reason why they're slow. Also, they're deprecated...

Comment: Do you need a fast mutable list/vector in R ? Don't know if suitable for your needs, but have a look at https://github.com/digEmAll/stdvectors package (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Comment: Oh, this looks like a cool package! Any chance you'd consider adding an S3 method to it such as `]<-`? I suspect it would make it more easy to use in the R setting (I'm not sure what it would do to performance though). Also, do you intend to add a vignette to it? (showing more real-world use cases, rather than only what is in the README?)

Comment: Well, I preferred not to add any S3 methods because stdvectors should be used to add/replace/erase values, but for complex subsetting etc, you should convert them back to R vectors... so I didn't want to give the feeling that they can be used as replacement for R vectors.

Comment: About the vignette, I didn't add any but maybe I will...