# How to create some of the exotic types?

Tags: r

I am intrigued by `?typeof`, which mentions values that can be returned. Is there a way to call `typeof(something)` and get one of the following?

> "promise", "char", "...", "any", "bytecode"

I discovered I can get two of the more exotic types that the help for `typeof` considers "unlikely to be seen at the user level", like so:

```
typeof(new("externalptr"))
# [1] "externalptr"

typeof(rlang::new_weakref(new("externalptr")))
# [1] "weakref"
```

but is there a way to get the others?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Before we try to get specific responses out of `typeof`, let's clarify what the function actually does. This requires a refresher on what a *type* is in R.

**Types**

Every R object is represented by a structure in the underlying C code called an `SEXP`, which contains a pointer to the actual data. Since there are different *types* of data structure that the `SEXP` could point to, each `SEXP` has a field called `SEXPTYPE` that tells R what sort of structure the `SEXP` is pointing at. This `SEXPTYPE` is stored as an integer.

When we call `typeof` in R, the integer value of the object's `SEXTYPE` is looked up in the [type table](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/44bcdf9a09d41f74ef8cc7832f18c6662ae2f263/src/main/util.c#L206), which ultimately returns a string to the console to give a human-readable description of the `SEXPTYPE` of the object. The type table therefore contains *all possible* outputs of `typeof`.

In this sense, the *type* of an object in R is the lowest-level description of what sort of object it is.

The `SEXPTYPE` values with entries in the type table are as follows:

| value | SEXPTYPE | Description | `typeof` output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NILSXP | NULL | "NULL" |
| 1 | SYMSXP | symbols | "symbol" |
| 2 | LISTSXP | pairlists | "pairlist" |
| 3 | CLOSXP | closures | "closure" |
| 4 | ENVSXP | environments | "environment" |
| 5 | PROMSXP | promises | "promise" |
| 6 | LANGSXP | language objects | "language" |
| 7 | SPECIALSXP | special functions | "special" |
| 8 | BUILTINSXP | builtin functions | "builtin" |
| 9 | CHARSXP | internal character strings | "char" |
| 10 | LGLSXP | logical vectors | "logical" |
| 13 | INTSXP | integer vectors | "integer" |
| 14 | REALSXP | numeric vectors | "double" |
| 15 | CPLXSXP | complex vectors | "complex" |
| 16 | STRSXP | character vectors | "character" |
| 17 | DOTSXP | dot-dot-dot object | "..." |
| 18 | ANYSXP | make “any” args work | "any" |
| 19 | VECSXP | list (generic vector) | "list" |
| 20 | EXPRSXP | expression vector | "expression" |
| 21 | BCODESXP | byte code | "bytecode" |
| 22 | EXTPTRSXP | external pointer | "externalptr" |
| 23 | WEAKREFSXP | weak reference | "weakref" |
| 24 | RAWSXP | raw vector | "raw" |
| 25 | S4SXP | S4 classes not of simple type | "S4" |

It *is* possible to get an object of each of these types in the console, but as far as I can tell, four of them cannot be obtained in base R alone. These are "promise", "char", "any" and "weakref". For these we need to use extra compiled code - either our own little snippets in `Rcpp`, or already-available functions in `rlang`.

Let's get an example of each valid *type* in the console.

**0: NILSXP**

This is just `NULL`

```r
n <- NULL
typeof(n)
#> [1] "NULL"
```

---

**1: SYMSXP**

This is an unevaluated `symbol`. We can get a symbol in several ways in base R, including `quote`, `substitute`, `bquote` and `str2lang`

```r
s <- quote(x)
typeof(s)
#> [1] "symbol"
```

---

**2: LISTSXP**

Despite the name, this is *not* used for `list` objects, but rather for *dotted pairlists*, as used in the `formals` of functions. Functionally, they are similar to standard lists, but are implemented differently in the underlying C code, and do have some important [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417134/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-a-pairlist-in-r)

```r
p <- pairlist(a = 1)
typeof(p)
#> [1] "pairlist"
```

---

**3: CLOSXP**

This is used to store *closures*, i.e. functions that are written in R code rather than being internal C functions.

```r
f <- function() {}
typeof(f)
#> [1] "closure"
```

---

**4: ENVSXP**

Used to store *environments*

```r
e <- new.env()
typeof(e)
#> [1] "environment"
```

---

**5: PROMSXP**

In R, a *promise* is made of two objects: a chunk of unevaluated code, plus a pointer to an environment in which that code should be evaluated. This is very similar to a `quosure` in the tidyverse ecosystem, except that one can assign and pass round a quosure quite easily, delaying evaluation until it is required. A promise is more evanescent; it will evaluate as soon as you assign it to a symbol, so to see one in the wild you need to have it contained in a list.

I can't find a way to create one using only base R, but we can obtain a promise using `rlang::node_car` on a `DOTSXP`.

```r
p <- list(rlang::node_car((function(...) get("..."))(a = 1)))

p
#> [[1]]
#> <promise: 0x0000021e05c3f870>

typeof(p[[1]])
#> [1] "promise"
```

---

**6: LANGSXP**

This is just an unevaluated chunk of code (though it has been parsed as syntactically correct before being stored). Again, this can be created by `quote` or `substitute`, but formulas are also stored as language objects:

```r
l <- hello ~ world
typeof(l)
#> [1] "language"
```

---

**7: SPECIALSXP**

This is only used for primitive functions which pass their arguments unevaluated to the internal R machinery:

```r
i <- `if`
typeof(i)
#> [1] "special"
```

---

**8: BUILTINSXP**

Again, this is only used to store the built-in functions, but these differ from "special" functions, in that their arguments are evaluated in R before being passed to the internal code.

```r
b <- `+`
typeof(b)
#> [1] "builtin"
```

---

**9: CHARSXP**

These are *not* used to store R's familiar character vectors, but instead are a character type used internally by R to store atomic character strings. This allows a cache of reusable strings, and allows character vectors (type `STRSXP`) to be more efficient. Note that R does *not* like dealing with `CHARSXP` outside of its internal functions. It will give warnings when you have one in the console, telling you that this type of object cannot have attributes.

Counter-intuitively, this is one of the hardest to make. Perhaps the easiest way is to create a `RAWSXP` then change the underlying type in compiled code.

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("SEXP mkchar(SEXP s) {SET_TYPEOF(s, 9); return s;}")

get_char <- function(){
  mkchar(as.raw(c(0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 
           0x6c, 0x64, 0x21, 0x00)))
}

chr <- get_char()

chr
#> <CHARSXP: "Hello World!">

typeof(chr)
#> [1] "char"
```

---

**10: LGLSXP**

These are the commonly-used logical vectors in R.

```r
l <- TRUE
typeof(l)
#> [1] "logical"
```

---

*If you're wondering about SEXPTYPE 11 and 12, these were previously used decades ago for factors and ordered factors, but are [not even defined any more](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/include/Rinternals.h#L122), so there are no hidden legacy types we can pull out of `typeof` corresponding to these*.

---

**13: INTSXP**

R uses different *types* for integers and double-precision floating point numbers, but will convert from integers to doubles with the slightest provocation. The difference between integers and doubles is to some extent abstracted away from the end-user by the fact that `INTSXP` and `REALSXP` are lumped together as the *mode* `"numeric"`

```r
I <- 1L
typeof(I)
#> [1] "integer"
```

---

**14: REALSXP**

These are the familiar numeric vectors

```r
r <- 1.1
typeof(r)
#> [1] "double"
```

---

**15: CPLXSXP**

Complex numbers have their own storage type and are easy to create. I'm not sure why they need their own storage type, as it seems they could just as easily be implemented in S3. Presumably this is partly historical and partly due to efficiency in interfacing with various math libraries.

```r
C <- 1 + 1i
typeof(C)
#> [1] "complex"
```

---

**16: STRSXP**

*This* is the familiar character vector.

```r
s <- "Hello world"
typeof(s)
#> [1] "character"
```

---

**17: DOTSXP**

The dots in some function formals that allow for extra arbitrary arguments to be passed are implemented as a pairlist of promises. This has its own storage mode called DOTSXP

Perhaps surprisingly, this can actually be obtained without any compiled code:

```r
d <- (function(...) get("..."))(a = 1)

d
#> <...>

typeof(d)
#> [1] "..."
```

---

**18: ANYSXP**

This isn't really a well-defined storage mode. As far as I can tell, it is used as a stand-in internally, predominantly for the implementation of S4 objects. The console will give you an error if you try to display an object of type "any", but it can be stored and its type reported correctly. I can't see a way to obtain it without just coercing an existing object via compiled code:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("SEXP get_any(SEXP s) {SET_TYPEOF(s, 18); return s;}")

a <- get_any(1:5)

a
#> Error: unimplemented type 'any' in 'PrintValueRec'

typeof(a)
#> [1] "any"
```

---

**19: VECSXP**

*This* is the familiar all-purpose R `list`

```r
l <- list()
typeof(l)
#> [1] "list"
```

---

**20: EXPRSXP**

Used for (lists of) unevaluated expressions

```r
e <- expression(hello * world)
typeof(e)
#> [1] "expression"
```

---

**21: BCODESXP**

Used for byte code of compiled functions.

```r
b <- .Internal(bodyCode(mean))
typeof(b)
#> [1] "bytecode"
```

---

**22: EXTPTRSXP**

This was already mentioned in the question and is here for completeness

```r
e <- new("externalptr")
typeof(e)
# [1] "externalptr"
```

---

**23: WEAKREFSXP**

This was already mentioned in the question and is here for completeness

```r
w <- rlang::new_weakref(.GlobalEnv)
typeof(w)
#> [1] "weakref"
```

---

**24: RAWSXP**

This is just an array of unsigned 8-bit integers

```r
r <- as.raw(1L)
typeof(r)
#> [1] "raw"
```

---

**25: S4SXP**

This is used for objects made in the native object-oriented S4 system

```r
setClass("R_obj", slots = c(a = "character", b = "numeric"))
s <- new("R_obj", a = "Hello world", b = 1)
typeof(s)
#> [1] "S4"
```

---

In addition to these 24 types, there are 3 other SEXPTYPEs defined which do not have names in the [type lookup table](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/44bcdf9a09d41f74ef8cc7832f18c6662ae2f263/src/main/util.c#L206) and therefore can't return unique names from `typeof`. These are 30 (NEWSXP),  31 (FREESXP) and 99 (FUNSXP). The first two are used internally for memory management / garbage collection, and should only ever exist for microseconds, and the third is used as a placeholder SEXPTYPE for lumping together closures / builtin functions / special functions when searching for objects of *mode* function. As far as I can tell, no SEXP ever actually has this SEXTYPE.

I'd be interested to hear whether anyone who has a way of creating a PROMSXP or WEAKREFSXP without using rlang / Rcpp. It would also be good to hear about any ways of creating a CHARSXP or ANYSXP without using compiled code (though these seem to be a bit unstable when used in the console however they are produced).

---

As a final note, the closely related concepts of *mode*, *storage mode* and *class* come up when talking about types. Both *mode* and *storage.mode* are essentially aliases for type, as described here:

**Storage mode**

The call `storage.mode(x)` simply calls `typeof(x)` and returns it, unless `typeof(x)` is "closure", "builtin" or "special", then `storage.mode` returns "function". It is therefore just a slight abstraction / simplification of *type*.

**Mode**

The call `mode(x)` also calls `typeof(x)` and simplifies closures / specials / builtins into the single mode "function". In addition, it returns "numeric" for both integer and real number types. It changes "symbol" to "name", and changes "language" to either "call" or "(", depending on whether the language object starts with a parenthesis.

This diagram gives the full mapping between type, storage mode and mode:
[image]

**Class**

You can use R every day without needing to know anything about type, mode and storage mode, but a competent R user needs to know the concept of *class*. It is an object's class that determines which methods are dispatched on calls to generic functions, and therefore it is class that controls an object's behaviour.

You can set an object's class simply by setting its class attribute:

```r
x <- 1
class(x) <- "foo"
class(x)
#> [1] "foo"
```

However, *every* object in R has a class, even objects with no class attribute:

```r
x <- 1:5
class(x)
#> [1] integer
```

This is because R determines an object's class via the C function [do_data_class](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/attrib.c#L606). If there is a "class" attribute set, then *that* is the class. If there is no "class" attribute set, then first R will check for a *dimension* attribute. If there is a non-zero dimension attribute, then the class will be an "array" (though if it has exactly two dimensions it will have the class `c("matrix", "array")`). If there is no class *or* dimension attribute then the *type* of the object is retrieved. Depending on the type, R will return:

- `"function"` for closures, builtin or specials
- `"numeric"` for `REALSXP` (though surprisingly *not* for `INTSXP`)
- `"name"` for symbols
- In the case of language objects, if the *first* symbol is `if`, `while`, `for`, `=`, `<-`, `(` or `{`, then this will be returned. Otherwise `"call"` is returned. This is quite an arcane system, which seems to be a way of handling different elements of the language's grammar.
- In all other cases, the *class* will be the `typeof` the object.

---

In summary, *type* is the *actual* type of the objects stored in memory, and *mode* is a partial abstraction of the actual type that gives us the familiar names we often think of as "basic types" in R. Storage mode is a close synonym for type with limited usefulness. Class is the most familiar and useful abstraction of data types in R, and if an object doesn't have a specified class, R will assign it an *implicit class* based on the above rules.

Comment: Wow that was quick, phenomenal answer again Allan. Unfortunately I don't have ability to accept it myself but it seems like @jakub is active so hopefully he will see this. A couple simplifications, for language you might just do `quote(hello * world)`, and for the dots, no need to nest function calls we can do : `(function(...) get("..."))(a = 1)`

Comment: @moodymudskipper thanks. It's an interesting question you have unearthed, and I'm not bothered about the answer being accepted - it's just a good opportunity to post an answer that demystifies some of the inner workings of R. I was wondering how to structure the answer and I thought it might be best to just cover all the types, exotic or not, since the non-exotic ones are easy. I used `str2lang` for variety, but will refine the dotsxp code: you are the master of the dots!

Comment: There is a special syntax to create CPLXSXP objects: e.g. `C <- 1 + 1i`. And the LANGSXP example can be simplified by using `quote()`: `l <- quotehello * world)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good tip for complex numbers. The str2lang was just for variety, but I have taken the opportunity to show that formulas are actually language objects too

Comment: Since this will be a precious reference about types in R, and even if it's slightly out of scope, would it make sense to mention the mode, storage.mode, and implicit class for all types when it's different from the type ?

Comment: @moodymudskipper I've added that as an addendum - at least for mode and storage mode. Implicit class probably strays a bit too far off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this, guys!

Comment: I awarded the bounty to the wrong answer by mistake :D. You get the new one as soon as I can give it!

Comment: @moodymudskipper really, you shouldn't have done that. It's fine - the Q&A has had plenty of exposure, and I don't really need the rep. It's very kind and community-minded of you though. Thank you.

Comment: does mode() return { for language objects starting with it (a la `(`)? I know class is special-cased here.

Comment: @MichaelChirico no, the only two outputs from `mode` for objects of type language are "call" and "(". The [source code for mode](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/base/R/mode.R#L19) is pretty short and straightforward, so you can see all the possibilities at a glance.

Comment: Yes that's why I had suggested to integrate the implicit class in the post, since it's mainly one of type or mode with this interesting "{" class for calls to `{`.

Comment: Sure, `class(quote({hello}))` returns `"{"`

Comment: @moodymudskipper ah, I see what you mean. The implicit class of objects of type language is a bit odd. It ultimately comes from the [lang2str function](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/attrib.c#L576) and if the language object starts with a `{`, `(`, `while`, `if`, or `for` it will return that when you call `class()`. For example `class(quote(if(hello == world){}))` returns `"if"`. I do think this strays a bit from the question and might make the answer too long, though might be worth documenting in a Collectives article or similar

Comment: Sure that's fair

Comment: @moodymudskipper I couldn't help myself adding it for completeness. What do you think? Too long?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I have expanded to include an explanation of where implicit classes differ from mode and type

Comment: I don't mind it, I think I would have just said on top that the implicit class of an object is generally the same as the type, and that exceptions are described in the relevant type description, the definition of implicit class along with the "foo" example, `do_data_class` etc might be out of scope. There might be also room on the diagram for a 4th col for the implicit class. The matrix/array case complicates  things a bit though...

Answer (score 6):

A promise is most commonly created when you call a function: the arguments you specify become promises.  However, it's difficult (impossible?) to get `typeof` to return "promise", because R code will cause the promise to be evaluated and it will become a different type.  You can see it as a promise in C code, but not in R.

A "char" is the type of a single entry in a character vector.  You can never see that in R code.

"..." is the list of arguments to a function passed in the `...` argument.  It's kind of like a promise; when you look at it, you usually force it to become something else.  However, @moodymudskipper pointed out that `environment()$...` returns the actual `...` object.

"any" is used somehow in the S4 system; I don't know if you can create a naked example.

"bytecode" is the compiled version of a function.  Once a function has been compiled (most functions in packages will be compiled), you can get its bytecode using `.Internal(bodyCode(fn))`, e.g.

```r
x <- .Internal(bodyCode(mean))
typeof(x)
#> [1] "bytecode"
compiler::disassemble(x)
#> list(.Code, list(11L, CALLSPECIAL.OP, 0L, RETURN.OP), list(UseMethod("mean"), 
#>     structure(c(NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), class = "expressionsIndex")))
```

Comment: To illustrate your point about promises, I tried this, and as expected, the promise collapsed into a value. `delayedAssign("cat_in_a_box", 2); typeof(cat_in_a_box)` returned `[1] "double"`.

Comment: About `...` this is incorrect. You can get it with `foo <- function(...) environment()$...; foo(x=1)` (won't work to get promises). I had fun with it with this package: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/dot3. I didn't know how to get bytecode, thanks for that!

Comment: @moodymudskipper:  corrected.

Comment: Upvoted, but accepted the other answer because it is extremely exhaustive.