# Check if in debug mode

Tags: r, debugging

I was wondering if we have a indicator tells whether the running function is in debug mode or normal running mode in Rstudio.

suppose we have a function:

```
f = function(){
   sink('new.txt')
   a = 1
   print(a)
   sink()
}
```

if we run into debug mode, then in debug mode, when you type a, the value will be printed to the files, you can't see anything in console.

I want to have an indicator like

```
 debug_mode = if_debug_mode()
```

and use that indicator to decide if activate or deactivate the sink function, like:

```
if(!debug_mode){
    sink('new.txt')
}
```

So in the debug mode, I could easily see the output, and don't dump the debug info into the new.txt

For this case,it has alternative way to solve this,like comment out the sink, but in some case, we may not want to run some time consuming code in debugging mode, so to skip part of the code in debugging mode is useful.

Comment: We have `help("isdebugged")` but it only works after `debug(f)` not after `debugonce(f)`.

Comment: I don't think there's a way from R code to know that it is being run in a debugger.  (I think there are actually two debuggers:  the one you get from `debug(f)`, and the one you get from `browser()`.)  But you need to look at flags in the C code of the evaluator to know if you're in one of those.  However, you can use `sink.number()` to find out if a sink is active, and `message()` which typically avoids being caught by `sink(file)`.

Comment: And of course you could set a global variable `debug_mode <- TRUE` to use in your test.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552940/get-browsing-state-in-a-function/63602125#63602125). I don't think it's an exact dupe, but it should make the answer pretty clear. I have spelled out how to implement the solution for this question in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This answer builds on the Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552940/get-browsing-state-in-a-function/63602125#63602125). It's *almost* a duplicate, except I think a demo to show it working in this scenario is valuable.

The first step is to write a little Rcpp function that returns `TRUE` if the context stack is greater than 0:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('bool is_browsing() { return Rf_countContexts(16,1) > 0;}')
```

Now we have a simple function `is_browsing` available in the global workspace:

```r
is_browsing()
#> [1] FALSE
```

We can use it inside your function as follows:

```r
f = function() {
  if(!is_browsing()) sink('new.txt')
  a = 1
  print(a)
  if(!is_browsing()) sink()
}
```

Now if we call

```r
f()
```

We just get `new.txt` written in the working directory with `[1] 1` written to the file.

However, if we do:

```r
debug(f)
f()
```

Then the debugger opens, and we can just step through it by hitting return each time.

```r
#> debugging in: f()
#> debug at #1: {
#>     if (!is_browsing()) 
#>         sink("new.txt")
#>     a = 1
#>     print(a)
#>     if (!is_browsing()) 
#>         sink()
#> }
Browse[2]> 
#> debug at #2: if (!is_browsing()) sink("new.txt")
Browse[2]> 
#> debug at #3: a = 1
Browse[2]> 
#> debug at #4: print(a)
Browse[2]> 
#> [1] 1
#> debug at #5: if (!is_browsing()) sink()
Browse[2]> 
#> exiting from: f()
```

You can see that after line 4, we get the result of `print(a)` printed to the console. No new.txt is created. Whilst browsing in any of these contexts, `is_browsing()` will return `TRUE`.

We get exactly the same output from `debugonce(f)`, and will also get the same thing if we include a call to `browser()` at the head of the function, with no file written in either case.

---

**Edit**

As Roland points out, `Rf_countContexts` is undocumented and although it is unlikely, there is a possibility the above solution would stop working if the internal implementation changed.

It is possible to write an equivalent method without using any undocumented functions. We have to re-define the RCNTXT struct since this is not exposed in the API, but this is at least documented in [R internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Contexts) paper, so this will remain valid as long as R internals does.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

extern void* R_GlobalContext ;

typedef struct {int tag, flags; union {int ival; double dval; SEXP sxpval;} u;
} R_bcstack_t;

typedef struct{jmp_buf jmpbuf; int mask_was_saved, saved_mask;} sigjmp_buf[1];

typedef struct RCNTXT {
  struct RCNTXT *nextcontext;
  int callflag;
  sigjmp_buf cjmpbuf;
  int cstacktop, evaldepth;
  SEXP promargs, callfun, sysparent, call, cloenv, conexit;
  void (*cend)(void *);
  void *cenddata;
  void *vmax;
  int intsusp, gcenabled, bcintactive;
  SEXP bcbody;
  void* bcpc;
  SEXP handlerstack, restartstack;
  struct RPRSTACK *prstack;
  R_bcstack_t *nodestack;
  R_bcstack_t *bcprottop;
  SEXP srcref;
  int browserfinish;
  SEXP returnValue;
  struct RCNTXT *jumptarget;
  int jumpmask;
} RCNTXT, *context;

attribute_hidden RCNTXT* R_ToplevelContext ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector is_browsing() {
  int n = 0;
  RCNTXT *cptr = (struct RCNTXT *)R_GlobalContext;
  RCNTXT *TL = (struct RCNTXT *)R_ToplevelContext;

  while( cptr != TL) {
    if( cptr->callflag == 16 ) n++;
    else if(cptr->callflag & 4 && RDEBUG(cptr->cloenv)) n++;
    cptr = cptr->nextcontext;
  }
  return n > 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a good online explanation for `Rf_countContexts` and the constants of its first argument or did you reverse engineer the source code to understand it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm afraid it was all reverse-engineering the C code (and this was before GitHub' search upgrade, so it took ages to find out what the [RCNTXT](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/include/Defn.h#L509) struct  was doing). The first parameter is `CTXT_BROWSER`, defined in the enum below the struct. The second parameter is an `int` that seems to be used as a boolean in [countContexts](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/context.c#L497). It just needs to be positive here.

Comment: 2 questions: 1 when we didn't need the function, how can we remove it from working env? 2 why we need a cpp function rather than an R function here?

Comment: Ok,I think I knew the anwser myself, according to the links related, the function is in global env, could be removed using rm(),and it you use cpp function since it is the cpp function Rf_countContexts() in main.C which tells you which level it uses. We can wrap it with both R or Cpp code.

Comment: 1 more tips: if you use this way, and using breakpoint in Rstudio to do this, the break point should be set before the function is_browsing being called. else the status is still in normal mode rather than debugging mode.

Comment: I think this needs a warning that the solution relies on undocumented internal code and there is no guarantee that it will work in future R versions.

Comment: @Roland fair point. I have included an addendum that does not require any undocumented functions and should be stable for as long as R Internals doesn't change.

Comment: Honestly, I'd think using `Rf_countContexts` is safer than using your alternative version.  Neither `Rf_countContexts` nor `RCNTXT` is part of the API, so both are subject to change without notice: and the R Internals manual even warns you to check information there against the sources, around the spot (in R 4.3.1) where it says it is for R 3.x.y.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, you're probably right. It seems very unlikely to me that the `RCNTXT` struct or `Rf_countContexts` would change in future versions of R, but the problem is that there is no way to get the browser context using _any_ documented part of the API. So if we really need such a function. we need to use non-API code. Whilst `Rf_countContexts` seems like a safer bet from reading the source code, it is _completely_ undocumented, whereas at least RCNTXT is acknowledged in R internals. The safest bet would be a feature request to the R Development team. In the meantime: caveat emptor!

Comment: I wouldn't say it is completely undocumented -- the comments in the source code are documentation.  I seem to remember some R core member saying that sometimes, the source is the best documentation, but all I can find now is `fortune(250)`, and Barry is not in R Core.

Comment: @user2554330 There are literally _no_ code comments in the entire R code base regarding `Rf_countContexts`. There is a brief (and somewhat opaque) preamble to the synonymous but unexposed `countContexts`. Fortunately, the function itself is so simple that even I can understand it. Of course, you (and Barry) are right about the source code being the best documentation in the sense that you can get more detail from it, (e.g. as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600201/how-to-create-some-of-the-exotic-types/77869794#77869794) ), but it can take a lot of work to get that detail!

Comment: @user2554330 Comments in source code are not official documentation. R-core members have often pointed out that undocumented internal code can change any time and you are not supposed to rely on it.

Comment: @Roland fair enough. I think then that this would have to count as a temporary hack. _Caveat Usor_ applies

Comment: @Roland:  I think you are right in the sense that `Rf_countContexts` is a "public" function, and according to Writing R Extensions those are "declared in an installed header file that are exported on all R platforms but are not documented and subject to change without notice."  So it is officially not documented, but in practice it is documented in the source.  It's not a "private" function, which according to WRE "should not be used".  So I'd say this is definitely "caveat usor", but it should work in all current and many past R versions.  It just might not work in new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think @AllanCameron's answer may be the best you'll be able to do to answer your exact question.  However, there are documented ways to know that you are debugging if you can control how the debugger was started.

For example, if you are starting it by inserting `browser()` calls into your source, you can add some code to be executed at the start. That code could set some global variable which your code could query.  For example, here's a crude attempt:

```r
f = function(){
  a = 1
  if (wantToDebug)
    browser(expr = setInDebugger(TRUE))
  
  message("inDebugger is ", inDebugger)
  setInDebugger(FALSE)
}

inDebugger <- FALSE
setInDebugger <- function(value) {
  inDebugger <<- value
  TRUE
}

wantToDebug <- FALSE
f()
wantToDebug <- TRUE
f()
```

As far as I can see, there's no way for `setInDebugger()` to modify the `on.exit()` code for `f()`, so this isn't that great, and calling `debug(f)` is even less flexible.

However, the `trace()` method of debugging is quite flexible.  For example,

```r
f = function(){
  a = 1
  
  message("inDebugger is ", inDebugger)
}

inDebugger <- FALSE
setInDebugger <- function(value) {
  inDebugger <<- value
  TRUE
}

f()

trace(f, 
      tracer = quote(browser(expr = setInDebugger(TRUE))), 
      exit = quote(setInDebugger(FALSE)),
      print = FALSE)

f()
```

I'm not certain, but I think RStudio uses `trace()` or something like it when you set breakpoints on particular lines in functions.  However, I don't know of a way to have it automatically execute code as above.  (To set the breakpoint on a particular line, you use the `at` argument to `trace()`,
or `utils::setBreakpoint()` which calls `trace()` after constructing the `at` argument.)

Comment: Thanks for bringing in the trace function here, what is the main difference between trace(f) and debug(f)? Is trace a more detailed device to be used for debugging?

Comment: Internally, `debug(f)` just sets a flag in the function object, whereas `trace(f)` makes a lot of changes, replacing the body of `f()` with new code.  That's why `trace()` is so flexible.

Comment: OK,Thanks for explain some detail here.