# What kind of object is `...`?

Tags: r, class, optional-parameters, typeof

I recently thought about the `...` argument for a function and noticed that R does not allow to check the class of the object.

```
f <- function(...) {
   class(...)
}

f(1, 2, 3)
## Error in class(...) : 3 arguments passed to 'class' which requires 1
```

Now with the quote

> “To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful:
>
> • Everything that exists is an object. • Everything that happens is a
>   function call."
>
> — John Chambers

in my head I'm wondering: What kind of object is `...`?

Comment: [Section 1.5.2 of the R Internals manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot-arguments) may be somewhat helpful. They are a special type of "pairlist". [Section 1.1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) tells us "Pairlists are rarely seen at R level, but are for example used for argument lists." Other things that are pairlists are language objects, such as formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What an interesting question!

Dot-dot-dot `...` is an object (John Chambers is right!) and it's a type of pairlist. Well, I searched the documentation, so I'd like to share it with you:

[R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot) document says:

> The ‘...’ object type is stored as a type of pairlist. The components of ‘...’ can be accessed in the usual pairlist manner from C code, but is not easily accessed as an object in interpreted code. The object can be captured as a list.

[Another chapter](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects) defines pairlists in detail:

> Pairlist objects are similar to Lisp’s dotted-pair lists.
>
> Pairlists are handled in the R language in exactly the same way as generic vectors (“lists”).

Help on [Generic and Dotted Pairs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html) says:

> Almost all lists in R internally are Generic Vectors, whereas traditional dotted pair lists (as in LISP) remain available but rarely seen by users (except as formals of functions).

And a nice summary is here at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417134/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-a-pairlist-in-r)!