# ellipsis ... as function in substitute?

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I'm having trouble understanding how/why parentheses work where they otherwise *should not work*®.

```r
f = function(...) substitute(...()); f(a, b)
[[1]]
a
[[2]]
b
# but, substitute returns ..1
f2 = function(...) substitute(...); f2(a, b)
a
```

Normally an error is thrown, *could not find function "..."* or *'...' used in an incorrect context*, for example when calling `(\(...) ...())(5)`.

**What I've tried**
I have looked at the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2b0818a47199a0b64b6aa9b9f0e53a1e886e8e95/src/main/coerce.c#L2763-L2895) of `substitute` to find out why this doesn't happen here. [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) 1.1.1 and 1.5.2 says `...` is of SEXPTYPE DOTSXP, a pairlist of promises. These promises are what is extracted by `substitute`.

```
#  \-substitute #R
#    \-do_substitute #C
#      \-substituteList #C recursive
#        \-substitute #C
```

Going line-by-line, I am stuck at `substituteList`, in which *h* is the current element of `...` being processed. This happens recursively at line 2832 `if (TYPEOF(h) == DOTSXP) h = substituteList(h, R_NilValue);`. I haven't found exception handling of a `...()` case in the source code, so I suspect something before this has happened.

In `?substitute` we find *substitute works on a purely lexical basis*. Does it mean `...()` is a [parser](https://colinfay.me/r-language-definition/parser.html) trick?

```r
parse(text = "(\\(...) substitute(...()))(a, b)") |> getParseData() |> subset(text == "...", select = c(7, 9))

#>                   token  text
#> 4        SYMBOL_FORMALS   ...
#> 10 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL   ...
```

The second ellipsis is recognized during lexical analysis as the name of a function call. It doesn't have its own token like `|>` does. The output is a pairlist ( `typeof(f(a, b))` ), which in this case is [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417134/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-a-pairlist-in-r) as a regular list **(?)**. I guess it is not a parser trick. But whatever it is, it has been around for a while!

[image: old tricks]

**Question**:
How does `...()` work?

Comment: Great question. THis is the undocumented behaviour of `substitute`. Would definitely love to know the solution to this

Comment: A related question on R-devel mailing list: [support of `substitute(...())`](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-March/079131.html). Didn't _really_ get answered did it?

Comment: @Henrik Yes, that question seems important. Is this part of the official API since it doesn't appear to be documented? Or is this documented (indirectly) and we just don't understand the documentation? Someone should follow up on R-devel.

Comment: @Henrik We can somewhat answer one of those questions: added between versions 1.3.1 (Sept 2001) and 1.4.1 (Jan 2002).  `(function(...) substitute(...()))(a,b)` runs fine in 1.4.1. It's been 20 years, and still not documented (?)

Comment: Well, `?substitute` does warn: "There is no guarantee that the resulting expression makes any sense." I'm guessing that that was intended as a catch-all for weird behaviour.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Note:** When referring to documentation and source code, I provide links to an *unofficial* [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/wch/r-source) of R's *official* [Subversion repository](https://svn.r-project.org/R/). The links are bound to [commit 97b6424](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83) in the GitHub repo, which maps to [revision `81461`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/?p=81461) in the Subversion repo (the latest at the time of this edit).

---

`substitute` is a "special" whose arguments are not evaluated ([doc](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/doc/manual/R-ints.texi#L2255-L2264)).

```r
typeof(substitute)
```

```
[1] "special"
```

That means that the return value of `substitute` may not agree with parser logic, depending on how the unevaluated arguments are processed internally.

In general, `substitute` receives the call `...(<exprs>)` as a `LANGSXP` of the form (pseudocode) `pairlist(R_DotsSymbol, <exprs>)` ([doc](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/doc/manual/R-ints.texi#L199-L207)). The context of the `substitute` call determines how the `SYMSXP` `R_DotsSymbol` is processed. Specifically, if `substitute` was called inside of a function with `...` as a formal argument and `rho` as its execution environment, then the result of

```c
findVarInFrame3(rho, R_DotsSymbol, TRUE)
```

in the body of C utility `substituteList` ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2827)) is either a `DOTSXP` or `R_MissingArg`—the latter if and only if `f` was called without arguments ([doc](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/doc/manual/R-ints.texi#L1015-L1040)). In other contexts, the result is `R_UnboundValue` or (exceptionally) some other `SEXP`—the latter if and only if a value is bound to the name `...` in `rho`. Each of these cases is handled specially by `substituteList`.

The multiplicity in the processing of `R_DotsSymbol` is the reason why these R statements give different results:

```r
f0 <- function() substitute(...(n = 1)); f0()
## ...(n = 1)
f1 <- function(...) substitute(...(n = 1)); f1()
## $n
## [1] 1
g0 <- function() {... <- quote(x); substitute(...(n = 1))}; g0()
## Error in g0() : '...' used in an incorrect context
g1 <- function(...) {... <- quote(x); substitute(...(n = 1))}; g1()
## Error in g1() : '...' used in an incorrect context
h0 <- function() {... <- NULL; substitute(...(n = 1))}; h0()
## $n
## [1] 1
h1 <- function(...) {... <- NULL; substitute(...(n = 1))}; h1()
## $n
## [1] 1
```

Given how `...(n = 1)` is parsed, you might have expected `f1` to return `call("...", n = 1)`, both `g0` and `g1` to return `call("x", n = 1)`, and both `h0` and `h1` to throw an error, but that is not the case for the above, mostly undocumented reasons.

#### Internals

When called inside of the R function `f`,

```r
f <- function(...) substitute(...(<exprs>))
```

`substitute` evaluates a call to the C utility `do_substitute`—you can learn this by looking [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/names.c#L122)—in which `argList` gets a `LISTSXP` of the form `pairlist(x, R_MissingArg)`, where `x` is a `LANGSXP` of the form `pairlist(R_DotsSymbol, <exprs>)` ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2874)).

If you follow the body of `do_substitute`, then you will find that the value of `t` passed to `substituteList` from `do_substitute` is a `LISTSXP` of the form `pairlist(copy_of_x)` ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2891-L2892)).

It follows that the `while` loop inside of the `substituteList` call ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2817)) has exactly one iteration and that the statement `CAR(el) == R_DotsSymbol` in the body of the loop ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2823)) is `false` in that iteration.

In the `false` branch of the conditional ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2839-L2845)), `h` gets the value
`pairlist(substituteList(copy_of_x, env))`. The loop exits and `substituteList` returns `h` to `do_substitute`, which in turn returns `CAR(h)` to R (source [1](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2849), [2](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2859), [3](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2894)).

Hence the return value of `substitute` is `substituteList(copy_of_x, env)`, and it remains to deduce the identity of this `SEXP`. Inside of *this* call to `substituteList`, the `while` loop has `1+m` iterations, where `m` is the number of `<exprs>`. In the first iteration, the statement `CAR(el) == R_DotsSymbol` in the body of the loop is `true`.

In the `true` branch of the conditional ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2824-L2837)), `h` is either a `DOTSXP` or `R_MissingArg`, because `f` has `...` as a formal argument ([doc](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/doc/manual/R-ints.texi#L1015-L1040)). Continuing, you will find that `substituteList` returns:

- `R_NilValue` if `h` was `R_MissingArg` in the first `while` iteration *and* `m = 0`,

or, otherwise,

- a `LISTSXP` listing the expressions in `h` (if `h` was a `DOTSXP` in the first `while` iteration) followed by `<exprs>` (if `m > 1`), all unevaluated and without substitutions, because the execution environment of `f` is empty at the time of the `substitute` call.

Indeed:

```r
f <- function(...) substitute(...())
is.null(f())
## [1] TRUE
f <- function(...) substitute(...(n = 1))
identical(f(a = sin(x), b = zzz), pairlist(a = quote(sin(x)), b = quote(zzz), n = 1))
## [1] TRUE
```

#### Misc

FWIW, it helped me to recompile R after adding some print statements to `coerce.c`. For example, I added the following before `UNPROTECT(3);` in the body of `do_substitute` ([source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/97b64247eb716e652e76d8eefffff53f21c2eb83/src/main/coerce.c#L2893)):

```c
    Rprintf("CAR(t) == R_DotsSymbol? %d\n",
            CAR(t) == R_DotsSymbol);
    if (TYPEOF(CAR(t)) == LISTSXP || TYPEOF(CAR(t)) == LANGSXP) {
        Rprintf("TYPEOF(CAR(t)) = %s, length(CAR(t)) = %d\n",
                type2char(TYPEOF(CAR(t))), length(CAR(t)));
        Rprintf("CAR(CAR(t)) = R_DotsSymbol? %d\n",
                CAR(CAR(t)) == R_DotsSymbol);
        Rprintf("TYPEOF(CDR(CAR(t))) = %s, length(CDR(CAR(t))) = %d\n",
                type2char(TYPEOF(CDR(CAR(t)))), length(CDR(CAR(t))));
    }
    if (TYPEOF(s) == LISTSXP || TYPEOF(s) == LANGSXP) {
        Rprintf("TYPEOF(s) = %s, length(s) = %d\n",
                type2char(TYPEOF(s)), length(s));
        Rprintf("TYPEOF(CAR(s)) = %s, length(CAR(s)) = %d\n",
                type2char(TYPEOF(CAR(s))), length(CAR(s)));
    }
```

which helped me confirm what was going into and coming out of the `substituteList` call on the previous line:

```r
f <- function(...) substitute(...(n = 1))
invisible(f(hello, world, hello(world)))
```

```
CAR(t) == R_DotsSymbol? 0
TYPEOF(CAR(t)) = language, length(CAR(t)) = 2
CAR(CAR(t)) = R_DotsSymbol? 1
TYPEOF(CDR(CAR(t))) = pairlist, length(CDR(CAR(t))) = 1
TYPEOF(s) = pairlist, length(s) = 1
TYPEOF(CAR(s)) = pairlist, length(CAR(s)) = 4
```

```r
invisible(substitute(...()))
```

```
CAR(t) == R_DotsSymbol? 0
TYPEOF(CAR(t)) = language, length(CAR(t)) = 1
CAR(CAR(t)) = R_DotsSymbol? 1
TYPEOF(CDR(CAR(t))) = NULL, length(CDR(CAR(t))) = 0
TYPEOF(s) = pairlist, length(s) = 1
TYPEOF(CAR(s)) = language, length(CAR(s)) = 1
```

Obviously, compiling R with debugging symbols and running R under a debugger helps, too.

#### Another puzzle

Just noticed this oddity:

```r
g <- function(...) substitute(...(n = 1), new.env())
gab <- g(a = sin(x), b = zzz)
typeof(gab)
## [1] "language"
gab
## ...(n = 1)
```

Someone here can do another deep dive to find out why the result is a `LANGSXP` rather than a `LISTSXP` when you supply `env` different from `environment()` (including `env = NULL`).

Comment: First, really neat approach! How to recompile R for troubleshooting deserves its own topic. In the case of `(\(...) substitute(...))(a, b)` only `a`  is returned. From your answer I understand this is because `...()` is `pairlist(R_DotsSymbol, <exprs>)`. But, I'm not entirely clear on why just `...` without parentheses does not follow the same path of `1+m` iterations giving the same result as `...()`.

Comment: In that case, `argList` gets the value `pairlist(R_DotsSymbol, R_MissingArg)` inside of `do_substitute` instead of `pairlist(pairlist(R_DotsSymbol, <exprs>), R_MissingArg)`. (Indeed, `...` by itself is a `SYMSXP`, whereas `...()` is a `LANGSXP`, so `do_substitute` is behaving consistently here.) It follows that `substituteList` returns to `do_substitute` the `LISTSXP` `pairlist(a, b)`, and that `do_substitute` returns to R the `SYMSXP` `a`.