# r - Assign output of functions to vector

Tags: r

I want to do a polynomial regression for polynomials from 1 to 10:

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Auto)

myvec <- vector(length=10)
for (i in 1:length(myvec)){
    myvec[i]<-lm(mpg~poly(acceleration, i, raw=TRUE))
}
```

But
    `summary(myvec[3])`
is different from:
`summary(var1 <- lm(mpg~poly(acceleration, 3, raw=TRUE)))`

How can I put output of functions into vectors with their original output type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this and it should work:

```
mylist.names <- rep("A",10)
mylist <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(mylist) <- mylist.names

for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  mylist[[i]]<-lm(mpg~poly(acceleration, i, raw=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: So you create vector of lists, and there you put output of lm. Why do you index by [[i]]? I see that mylist[[i]] is the same as mylist[i] ,mylist[i] is i-th part of first vector.

Comment: Try `class(mylist)`. It is actually not a vector. It is a list. What I did before I started the loop was just a little hack to create a list with 10 empty entries. You could also just do `mylist <- list()` and let the loop run from 1 to 10. Here is a question discussing the thing I think you are worrying about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r.

Comment: as (the other) @Alex notes, `vector(mode= "list", ...)` creates a list.... I believe you could use `mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(i) {lm(mpg~poly(acceleration, i, raw=TRUE))})` instead of the for loop (though I haven't tested it.