# Creating a variable name by code in R

Tags: r

I would like to produce the names of my variables automatically in R. For example in this code below, I tried to generate the variable name using `paste0` and associate the names in a vector inside a `for` structure.

```
names = c('john', 'marie', 'joe')


for(i in 1:length(names)){

paste0('summary_of_', names[i]) = 2

}
```

It does not work and this error was shown:

```
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is it possible to create the variable names in a similar way?

Comment: The hint of where to look is in the error. Look at `assign`.

Comment: That´s exactly what I was looking for! Thx!

Comment: Also: don't do this. It's a terrible idea. Use data.table or dplyr or anything else to do your group summaries. Or at the very least store the results in a list. But don't dynamically create variables like that. It's messy and not worth it.

Comment: `lapply` (or `Map` if multivariate) usually makes this unnecessary.

Comment: Agree with @Dason. It's a bad idea to write your variables as object in the user environment. Learn [how to deal with list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r) instead.

Comment: regardless of how its done,  `names` is a function and reserved