# Assign different names to models build during a loop

Tags: r, regression, models, rda

I made multiple models and stored them in separate names in a loop

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1000:1009,each = 20), y = rnorm(20*10), x = rnorm(20*10))

loc.vec <- c(1000:1009)

for(l in seq_along(loc.vec)){

      loc <- loc.vec[[l]]
      df.loc <- df[df$loc.id == loc,]
      mdl <- with(df.loc,lm(y ~ x))
      saveRDS(mdl,paste0("mod",loc,".mg.",".rda"))
      rm(mdl)
  }
```

When I try to reload the model in the loop:

```
  loc.vec <- c(1000:1009)

  for(l in seq_along(loc.vec)){

    loc <- loc.vec[[l]]
    readRDS(paste0("mod",loc,".mg.",".rda"))
  }
```

How do I load them such that my global environment has models as `mod.1000.mg`, mod.1001.mg, mod.1002.mg and so on

Comment: Actually it was just for demonstration purpose. The models are saved by different names as demonstrated

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example for testing

Comment: 1. It's a bad idea to create numerous variables with generated names.  Just put the results in a list.  2. If you're using `saveRDS`, you should use `readRDS` to read the file, not `load`.

Comment: Thank you . I have edited my question and also tried your suggestions. However, my global environment is empty

Comment: I suggest looking at the `lmList` function in the `lme4` package.

Comment: YOu may need to assign it

Comment: [Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) [are](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list) [great](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-use-lists-in-r/)[!](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html)